# How to filter in rows where any column is null in pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, filter, pyspark, null

It has to be somewhere on stackoverflow already but I'm only finding ways to filter the rows of a pyspark dataframe where 1 specific column is null, not where any column is null.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
my_dict = {"column1":list(range(100)),"column2":["a","b","c",None]*25,"column3":["a","b","c","d",None]*20}
my_pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

sparkDf = spark.createDataFrame(my_pandas_df)
sparkDf.show(5)
```

[image]

I'm trying to **include** any row with null values on any column of my dataframe, basically the opposite of this:

```
sparkDf.na.drop()
```

Comment: your question is not clear. do you want to find those rows where all columns are null, or find all rows where all columns can be null (any col can be null)? a sample output with appropriate results would help people answer

Comment: `sparkDf.na.drop(how='any').show(5)` ?

Comment: @murtihash tks for pointing it out, I meant if any of the columns has a null value, it shall be included.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For including rows having any columns with `null`:

```
sparkDf.filter(F.greatest(*[F.col(i).isNull() for i in sparkDf.columns])).show(5)
```

For excluding the same:

```
sparkDf.na.drop(how='any').show(5)
```